# What preposition should be used in "Moving something __ M meters"?

Tags: prepositions

I have four guesses so far:

> none, "*on*", "*for*", and "*by*".

Comment: What is "smth"?

Comment: @Scott - dictionary shorthand: smth/sb = something/somebody.

Comment: I assumed Scott knew what it meant and was pointing out that we ought not be using this kind of shorthand in our questions and answers here.  And I agree!

Comment: Why on Earth would you close the question with this reasoning after we already understood each other and found the answer? I find that highly inadequate, @Chenmunka and others (can only append one of you by the site limitation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the best option will be 'by':

> move something *by* N meters.

But I think no preposition also works:

> move something N meters.

Comment: Yes, just say *Move something N meters.*

Answer (score 0):

They are all fine, also:

> move something **over** N meters.

Comment: **Move on 5 meters** and **move for 5 meters** are not correct, neither is **move over 5 meters**. `Move over` means to move to free up some space.

Comment: @ArsenY.M. I missed "on" which is not correct. However both "for" and "over" are perfectly fine. Maybe English is not your first language..."move over" has at least two meanings.

Comment: English is not my first language, you are right, but cannot agree with you, can you refer to some reliable sources?

Comment: @ArsenY.M. OK..."Moving something for 5 meters" is pretty basic English. Using "over" in this case is a bit more subtle, but it refers to the *duration* of the movement. "Moving it over 5 meters caused the bottom to heat up". By "over" here I don't mean "greater than", but rather the "5 meters" becomes a noun with causative effect, in this case friction on the bottom of the thing being moved. It is perhaps more commonly used with time. If I say "the event was held over 2 days", I don't mean a duration greater than 2 days...and it is the same with distance but less commonly used.

Comment: your comment makes sense to me, but still that sounds odd to me, I even like `move it over by 5 meters` more.

Comment: @ArsenY.M. "move it over by 5 meters" is what your FIRST comment described - freeing up some space.